# How to make a data construct in R which contains two components?

Tags: r

How to make a data construct in R which contains two components, say

```
x <- (a,b)
```

, and make two functions to read and return the two components separately, say function 'car(x)' which will return 'a' and function 'cdr(x)' will return 'b'. And we make the components of the construct can also be constructs, say if

```
a <- (1, 2)
b <- (3, 4)
```

then 'car(car(x))' will return '1', 'cdr(car(x))' will return '2', 'car(cdr(x))' will return '3' and 'cdr(cdr(x))' will return '4'.

Comment: Have you tried anything? Where exactly are you getting stuck? If you want one object to hold multiple values, the more generic way to do that is a `list()`. You can add a class attribute if you want to make your own S3 class to easily give that list different behaviors.

Comment: help("list"); help("[[")

Comment: In the simple case, `a <- list(1, 2); b <- list(3, 4); x <- list(a,b); car <- function(x) x[[1]]; cdr <- function(x) x[[2]]` should work.

Comment: Yes, this works. Thanks